# Unable to load the servlet in jsp form tag

Tags: java

My jsp page ExecutionIframe.jsp

```
<form target="results" id="form1" name="mxform" action="/SaveMxAdapter" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

[image]

My Project structure

I am adding my jsp page to iframe an add to the string

```
form+="<iframe id=\"ExecutionIframe\" name=\"ExecutionIframe\" src=\"/polarion/mxadapter/ExecutionIframe.jsp\" border=\"0\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"100%\" width=\"100%\" scrolling=\"yes\">";
                form+="</iframe>"
```

My web.xml is

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>SaveMxAdapterServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
com.danlaw.polarion.mxadapter.servlet.SaveMxAdapterServlet</servlet-class>

</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>SaveMxAdapterServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/SaveMxAdapter</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But the jsp page unable to call the servlet

i got error like

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /SaveMxAdapter was not found on this server.

Comment: Check the *web.xml* file if you map the url with your servlet.

Comment: you please put the web.xml or if you use annotation the code of servlet

Comment: I add the web.xml

Comment: ok.It 's look ok. did you stop your server and re-deployed the app and see if the problem persist. if so, please could you share your project.

Comment: sorry i cannot share my project.when i change the action like action="/polarion/mxadapter/SaveMxAdapter" i got error like An error occurred while configuring data!

Comment: can you put all the codes in your web.xml. as in all.

Comment: may i need put my jsp page in web.xml

Comment: Have you implemented the method for post-requests within your Servlet?

Comment: yes i implemented